# How to force main part of the website to stay below the header on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to position the main content of the page below the header, when the page is resized. When the window is maximized everything looks well. When resizing the window to smaller width, the main content is hidden by the header.

I am using rails with html, css, jQuery and javascript.

It is a lot of code. I do not really know what is important.

The app is based on railstutorial from michael hartl. Here is the link to the source code on bitbucket. https://bitbucket.org/railstutorial/sample_app_4th_ed.

The resizing does not work on in railstutorial from Michael Hartl too.

When resize the window, the header overlaps the main content of the page.

Comment: Can you give some sample code? Really, this all depends on how your header is positioned/resizes.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, perhaps you could provide some example code of what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
    $('#main').css('margin-top', '' + $(".container").height()+'px');
});
```

The problem was that I had a div with id "header" and id "main". That did not work.

In the header was a div with a class "container". $(".container").height() worked.

```
<div id="header">
      <%= render "layouts/header" %>
</div>
<div id="main">main content</div>
```

In the view layout/header is a div class="container"